# The number of failing rows exceeds the maximum specified (Microsoft JET Database Engine (80004005): Spreadsheet is full.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

I would like to ask help regarding this error. Here are the details regarding this error.

Step Error Source: Microsoft Data Transformation Services (DTS) Data Pump

Step Error Description:The number of failing rows exceeds the maximum specified. (Microsoft JET Database Engine (80004005): Spreadsheet is full.)

Step Error code: 8004206A

Step Error Help File:sqldts80.hlp

Step Error Help Context ID:0

I'm wondering on where can I locate the specific location of the error for this and other details.

Comment: Since the error tells you the 'spreadsheet is full', presumably the step where you write rows to your spreadsheet?

Comment: So I have to check on my excel files for this right?

Comment: No, you have to open the DTS package and find the step that writes to excel, and then see what it is actually doing...

Answer (score 0):

The number of records maxed out the number of available records in Excel. What I did was to copy the records and save it in Excel 2007 as this can hold around 1 million rows.